# Conversion of varchar to Number and make comparasion in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have two columns in table both have datatype as varchar2.
Now i want to get data based on input value and based on this my select query looks like this:

```
    select fromtime, totime from temp_trd_shr where 
fromtime <= '08:00' and  totime >='10:00'
```

Fromtime: varchar2(50)
totime  : varchar2(50)
08:00 & 10:00   : input value (in string and formate is always fix like xx:xx)
Oracle 11g

i tried with to_number but i am not able to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE temp_trd_shr
(
    fromtime VARCHAR2(5)
,   totime   VARCHAR2(5)
);

INSERT INTO temp_trd_shr VALUES ('01:00', '18:00');
INSERT INTO temp_trd_shr VALUES ('02:00', '17:00');
INSERT INTO temp_trd_shr VALUES ('03:00', '16:00');
INSERT INTO temp_trd_shr VALUES ('04:00', '15:00');
INSERT INTO temp_trd_shr VALUES ('05:00', '14:00');
INSERT INTO temp_trd_shr VALUES ('06:00', '13:00');

INSERT INTO temp_trd_shr VALUES ('08:30', '09:30');
INSERT INTO temp_trd_shr VALUES ('08:45', '09:45');

SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    temp_trd_shr;
-- 8

SELECT  *
FROM    temp_trd_shr
WHERE   TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(fromtime, ':')) <= TO_NUMBER(REPLACE('08:00', ':'))
AND     TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(totime,   ':')) >= TO_NUMBER(REPLACE('10:00', ':'))
ORDER   BY
        1
;
/*
01:00   18:00
02:00   17:00
03:00   16:00
04:00   15:00
05:00   14:00
06:00   13:00
*/
```